# grid column inner input pushing upper div when height grows with too much text

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, tailwind-css

The best way to understand what is happening to me is simply watching the video:

[video of content inside input pushes up div of messages - NOT WORKING](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2ubdzy3whczchf/Screen%20Recording%202020-05-14%20at%2011.07.13%20PM.mov?dl=0)

The best way to see how I would like this to work is with this video taken from discord.com chat community

[The way it should work](https://www.dropbox.com/s/17z9o4frun69wda/Screen%20Recording%202020-05-14%20at%2011.04.40%20PM.mov?dl=0)

I'm using TailWindCSS, and I have - in the simplest example- something like a grid with 3 columns, but if you click and see the two videos you will understand what is happening, and what I want.

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-2 mx-2">
 <div>
   // lots of clients
 </div>
 <div>
   <div>lots of messages - this needs to scroll also</div>
   <input type="text"></input>
</div>
</div>
```

If someone can put a codepen, sandbox, jsbin, anything would help!

Comment: Can you put up a working snippet to work of off, that div  is growing downward instead of upward a simple alignment property should fix it however we need more context.

Comment: Hi @ZohirSalak, thanks for taking the time to look at my issue, sorry I couldn't post a working snippet, I was overwhelmed for days with this, and I tried to put something but couldn't replicate my issue on a snippet, again, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Well, sadly a simple `overflow-hidden` was causing this horrible issue, I honestly solved it by trial/error, since I'm not even close to being good at CSS.